# Need to fetch a JSON response for the 1st occurrence using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to fetch the JSON response from for the field(same name) which holds different value . But I need to fetch the value for the 1st occurrence.
Lets say i need to fetch "status" that has multiple occurrence. But i need to pull the 1st i.e "new"

{"ticketId":"216574537","timestamp":"3699689369843","targetType":"TMDeviceTicket","number":"4","time":"03/16/2018 11:30:00",`"status":"new",`"partOns":[],"itrEtrs":[{"componentId":"218318169","creationTimestamp":"03/28/2018 11:07:00","deviceType":"LAT","itrFlag":"false","restorationTimestamp":"03/28/2018 16:00:00","stormMode":"N"},

[{"oopId":"116400085","timestamp":"3699689369919","targetType":"TMRepairActionRefuseLateral","auto":"true","description":"Refuse B Lateral","deviceFplId":"268221704","actualDeviceType":"LATU","deviceDdbKey":"8614152820","deviceTroubleCoordinateX":"863937","deviceTroubleCoordinateY":"459296","childDevices":"List(268233640, 268233641, 268233642)","previousProtectiveDeviceStack":"List(23282601, 23281142)","discSwitch":"Refuse B Lateral","fuseSize":"65","fuseType":"K","operatedDevice":"fuse","overhead":"false","phase":"B","rcOff":"false","resolutionDateTime":"03/28/2018 11:29:00","scheduled":"true",`"status":"complete",`"view":"Lateral","identitySetRepairAction":[]},

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to get first status which is on top level it is enough to use the following JSON Path expression:

   ```
   $.status
   ```

   [image: JMeter JSON top level occurrence]
2. If you want to get all statuses - use "deep scan" operator:

   ```
    $..status
   ```

   [image: JMeter JSonPath deep scan]

More information:

- [JSON Path Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators)
- [JSON Path Examples](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#path-examples)
- [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)